# Declare iribboncontrol and set id

Tags: excel, vba

I have my own ribbon in an addin.  I use a generic callback function to process the button presses.  Fairly standard code...

```
Private Sub MikeyButtonPress(Control As IRibbonControl)
Select Case Control.ID
Case "UpdatePriceHistoryButton"
    Call MikeyUpdatePriceHistory
    etc.
```

I like to work at a high level and sometimes I like to go and press a button from within VBA.  So I wrote...

```
Dim this As IRibbonControl
this.ID = "UpdatePriceHistoryButton"
Call MikeyButtonPress(this)
```

However, I get error message "Can't assign to read-only property" at the line

```
this.ID = "UpdatePriceHistoryButton"
```

Does anyone know how to set a local IRibbonControl.Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign an ID to such a control. It already has a unique read only one, which cannot be modified. But, try please the next approach:

Adapt the control `Sub` in this way:

```
Private Sub MikeyButtonPress(Control As IRibbonControl, Optional strTestID As String)
  If strTestID <> "" Then
    Select Case strTestID
      Case "UpdatePriceHistoryButton"
          Call MikeyUpdatePriceHistory
          'do here whatever you need...
          '...
      Case "Test ID"
          MsgBox strTestID
    End Select
    Exit Sub 'or not, if you need that the Ribbon control standard behavior to also run
  End If
  'Do watever pressing the Ribbon control should do
  '....
End Sub
```

And call it in the next way:

```
Sub testAbove()
  MikeyButtonPress Nothing, "Test ID"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mikey: did you find time to test the above approach? If yes doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about adding an optional parameter.  I've posted how I would use it a bit differently.

Comment: @Mikey: Glad I could help! I would say that your solution is similar. I couldn't know how you will use it. I tried offering a solution to accept such calls from multiple other controls/purposes and using `Select Case` you can switch the solution according to the specific received string. So, do you consider that my answer did not answer your question?

Comment: Your answer did answer my question.  I'm happy to give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

If setting IRibbonControl.ID is not possible, then adding an optional parameter is a good solution.  I would use it a bit differently though...

```
Private Sub MikeyButtonPress(Control As IRibbonControl, Optional strTestID As String)
Dim sgButton As String
If strTestID <> "" Then
    sgButton = strTestID
Else
    sgButton = Control.ID
End If

Select Case sgButton
'Now the rest is as before
Case "UpdatePriceHistoryButton"
    Call MikeyUpdatePriceHistory
    etc.
```